# Can a detection be written from Github audit events that finds commit/pushes done after review approvals in pull requests?

Tags: audit, detection, github

I'm attempting to come up with a detection for when devs commit/push changes to pull requests after they have been reviewed and approved but before they have been merged.

There are various actions that I've found that seem useful like `pull_request.merge` and `pull_request_review.submit` which identify the `pr` and timestamp, however frustratingly, `git.push`, while containing timestamps, only identifies the repo.

Are there other event actions, possibly corollary but guaranteed to exist around `git.push` that I can rely on instead?